# Filtering files using recursive grep then using sed on them inline

Tags: sed, grep, xargs

If I, for example, want to open all files with the `int` statement in them, I use grep and pipe the search results to `vim` using `xargs`

```
grep -rl 'int' . | xargs vim
```

Typically, if I want to replace `int` with `float`, I do so like through `sed` like so

```
sed 's/\<int\>/float/g' foo.c
```

But how would I combine the two if I want to find all files that have the word `int` in them and then do word replacement on the file inline (eg. `sed -i 's/\<int\>/float/g'`)

Comment: Could you do something like `grep -rl 'int' . | xargs vim -s :s/int/float/g`?

Comment: @jared_mamrot, it's funny you ask, but I tried `bufdo s/int/float/g` but I think syntastic interfering with it as it only works on the first `int` it finds (also it gives like 50 errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how would I combine the two

You would do just:

```
grep -rl 'int' . | xargs sed -i 's/\<int\>/float/g'
```

Comment: Oh, I figured `sed` would treat input from STDIN as the content and not the filename

Comment: And that's what `xargs` is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a file of commands to vim using the `-s` flag, so I believe you can create a 'commands' file called "cmd.vim" which contains the line `:s/int/float/g` then use `grep -rl 'int' . | xargs vim -s cmd.vim`.

### EDIT

This is if you want to keep the files open in vim after you make the change from int to float; if you just want to make the change @KamilCuk's answer is better